# Any public datasets of authentication logs?

Tags: security, authentication, dataset, data-mining, mail-server

I'm looking for login logs, particularly from a mail server, to use as sample data. I've looked through a lot of public datasets but have been unable to find anything of the sort.

I'd like to be able to look at a log showing login attempts, with fields like time stamp, requester IP address, user account, success/fail, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised you did not find anything.

1. the **information is sensitive**, and should not be shared. For example someone might accidentially mistype their password as login name. In the logs this will show up as failed login, and the next login from the same IP might then be the appropriate username.
2. this data is of little use to anyone, in particular if it is historic or has been anonymized. Why would anyone bother to share this kind of data?
3. Furthermore, login (and attack, assuming that you are looking into that) patterns change over time. So any conclusion drawn from historic data will likely no longer hold.

So you'll have to get this data fresh, and under NDA from someone that trusts you to not misuse it. If it actually *is* of any use.

You might have better success if you would look for aggregated data. Temporal patterns of user activity vs. failed logins, for example.  But in any way, this site is about *programming* questions, not "where do I get data". You'll have to use Google mostly.

Comment: I realize the data is sensitive, but it could be anonymized. Historic data would suffice. I thought a question about sample data would fit into the category of practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession - but if this is the wrong place for it, is there another Q&A site or forum that may be better suited for my question? Thanks.

Comment: You should at least give away what you are trying to do. Even if someone by chance happens to have access to such data, he might be anonymizing it a way that makes your analysis moot: randomizing all IPs, all user names and all timestamps, for example.